# page redirect in angular if modal is clicked

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using **ng-app** in **bootstap** template in html.

When I click on the link which is assigned to *modal* the location changes to page.html#/contact

So, when I use routes in the page the **ng-view** of the page is changing.

Is there any way so that the page location does not change?

```
<li> <a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact Us</a></li>
<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog  modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h4>Video</h4>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

mySite.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
      templateUrl : "grid.jsp",
      controller :'homeController'
    })
    .when('/Videos',{
      templateUrl : "Videos/grid.jsp",
      controller : 'alluserCtrl'
    })
    .when('/user/current',{
      templateUrl : "userDetails.html",
      controller : "userDetailsCtrl"
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This blog entry](http://aashishkoirala.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/angular-bootstrap-modal/) provides an example of a directive that removes the need for `data-toggle` and replaces it with `ng-click` plus some javascript code to show/hide the modal.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to pass your routes in html5 mode, it will remove the # sign and since the modal is using that you may not be redirected.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

You can also listen for the `$routeChangeStart` event and prevent the default behaviour of redirect if it correspond to the "route" of your modal.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using href attribute I have used data-target it worked :-)

```
<a data-target="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact Us</a>
```